# SharePoint Menus and JQuery

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, master-page, branding

I use Muse exports for branding for SharePoint 2013, and usually have no problem. However, this time the jquery isn't loading. I've even tried a different menu to make sure it wasn't something with Muse (it wasn't).

These are menus that expand vertically when you click on them.

I've retooled the links and put the Jquery in the MasterPage library, Style Libraray and Site Assets and tried linking to them, none seem to work. The mouseover works because it changes color, but not the part that makes them expand/drop down.

Anyone else have this issue?